# A good ol'e Riddle. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I reach towards the heavens
>
> I hold treasure within
>
> And throughout many ages I've shed some skin
>
> I've watched as nations rise and fall
>
> Sturdy, rock, through it all

What am I?

Hint:

> I'm very well know, and popular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Topples answer:

> Pyramid

I reach towards the heavens

> Self explanatory

I hold treasure within

> Pyramids were built above Pharaoh tombs which were typically packed with large amounts of ancient treasures and possessions for the Pharaoh to use in the afterlife.

And throughout many ages I've shed some skin

> This could refer to the natural erosion/weathering of rock. Or it could refer to the fact many of these ancient tombs have been broken into by explorers.

I've watched as nations rise and fall

> Egypt has seen many rulers throughout the ages, from the very first ancient kingdoms thousands of years ago, to Roman, English, and French rule (and probably more)

Sturdy, rock, through it all

> Amazingly, many of these pyramids are still standing!

Comment: very nice, glad someone made an effort to clarify

Comment: skin: the (Egyptian)  pyramids originally had a smooth stone surface, but that has been looted for buiding material leaving the steps visible today.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](/a/38923).

Comment: Yeah, hence why I credited the guy

Answer (score 12):

I am guessing

> A pyramid.  
> They point upward and hold jewelry and other artifacts.
>   They have been around for thousands of years, long enough to see nations rise and falls (as well as erode....or shed some skin). 
>  Made of rocks/stones and of course very well known!

Comment: Correct!, but it's not quite as good and explained as the others.  Can you try to expand on this

Comment: I don't see the point.  I seem to have been skipped over because I said they have treasure instead of treasure because pharaoh.  To me I said everything I just didn't over explain it.

Comment: Shouldn't this answer get the credit for solving the riddle first, 3 hours before the accepted answer? I'm new to this site, but that seems like the most important point.  This question is now on the hot questions list, so the accepted answer will probably get many upvotes.

Comment: Imagine a question on StackExchange asking: Can I do this in Java? Person responds No. as their whole answer. Then twenty minutes later someone writes an in-depth explanation, including things such as reason the design decisions were made and contrasting it to different languages. In this case it is less distinct, but Dahui's answer hits all the hints, in an easily digestible format.  Topple gives a pretty good answer but doesn't really put it in the context of the riddle to make it easier for the reader to see connections.

Comment: Yeah I apologize for the formatting.  I am on mobile and had difficulty with formatting an answer on another question right before this one.  But I don't apologize for my answer, since I went out of my way to touch upon all the clues.  I specifically tried to do that for everyone.

Answer (score 7):

My shot in the dark:

> A mountain

I reach towards the heavens

> Well this is obvious. Mountains point to the sky

I hold treasure within

> There are many mines in the mountains for extracting different metals including the precious ones.

And throughout many ages I've shed some skin

> A mountain format is changing over long periods of time.

I've watched as nations rise and fall
Sturdy, rock, through it all

> Even if they change over long periods of time, in the course of one's life, mountains appear as unchanged even for generations. (why you use words I had to look up on the net as "sturdy"? :D ).

Comment: This fits great, but this wasn't the answer.  Might've well have (:

Comment: There cam be an (abandoned?) mine in a mountain, containing minerals.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be

> **clouds**?

I reach towards the heavens

> The heavens are often imagined to be above the sky and the clouds form and stay in the skies.

I hold treasure within

> Clouds hold water, which is the key to life on earth. Periodic rainfall is also important to create habitable zones on the planet.

And throughout many ages I've shed some skin

> The shedding of skin could be a metaphor for rainfall or precipitation in other forms.

I've watched as nations rise and fall

> Clouds have existed long before humanity, they have been there while civilizations grew and crumbled.

Sturdy, rock, through it all

> *Not sure about this clue*

I'm very well know, and popular.

> Clearly everyone would know about clouds and the purpose they serve. They are popular because they provide shade on a sunny day.

Comment: Pretty good attempt, but again not quite

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing...

> A flagpole (a bit of a long shot, I know)

---

Explanation:

I reach toward the heavens

> Tall

I hold treasure within

> Not sure

And throughout many ages I've shed some skin

> Flags as "skin" going up and down ("shedding")

I've watched as nations rise and fall

> National flags rising up and down

Sturdy, rock, through it all

> Standing sturdy through wars and conflicts (not sure)

Hint: I'm very well know(n), and popular.

> They're everywhere in cities

Who am I?

> A flagpole!

Comment: It's crazy to see what you guys come up with! This wasn't my intent, but it's still a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit far fetched but, I think, it is

> Trees!

I reach towards the heavens

> Tall trees...(Eucalyptus)

I hold treasure within

> Oxygen and glucose!No less than treasure. Saves us humans.

And throughout many ages I've shed some skin

> Shedding of bark of some trees.

I've watched as nations rise and fall

> Not sure about this.. maybe some trees live forever.(Banyan tree has a lifespan of 200 years)

Sturdy, rock, through it all

> Trees are very tough. Not easy to cut or destroy them.

Comment: As for "I've watched nations rise and fall" your answer surely fits: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oldest_trees

Answer (score 1):

A bit more abstract:

> An athlete?

I reach towards the heavens

> Striving to earn olympic gold or another award

I hold treasure within

> Hope, desire to do well, ambition, potential.

And throughout many ages I've shed some skin

> Long time spent training. Sporting injuries and other setbacks.

I've watched as nations rise and fall

> Watching other athletes climb to the top and fall back. Some retire, some become too old, some are banned for drugs cheating.

Sturdy, rock, through it all

> Training hard, being consistent. Not being swept around by the media or other athletes. Unaffected by the world, only concentrating on the main goal.

Comment: wait... how do you hide your answers?

Comment: You type `>!` in front of the text you want to hide. For instance: `>! This will be hidden`

Comment: thats useful to know